# Does xlwt module support INDIRECT?

Tags: python, xlwt, indirection

I used the following codes, but it doesn't work. I checked the xls. The formula is filled in correctly, but remains as a text entry. If to press ENTER to active this cell, it works.

```
sheet1.write(1, 1, xlwt.Formula('INDIRECT(\"\'sheet1\'!B1\")'))
```

I find INDIRECT is declared in xlwt\ExcelMagic.py:

```
all_funcs_by_name = {
    # Includes Analysis ToolPak aka ATP aka add-in aka xcall functions,
    # distinguished by -ve opcode.
    # name: (opcode, min # args, max # args, func return type, func arg types)
    # + in func arg types means more of the same.
...
'INDIRECT'    : (148, 1,  2, 'R', 'VV'),
...
```

Can anyone suggest how to use INDIRECT formula?

Answer (score 0):

`xlwt` has issues with compiling formulas that contain some functions that should return references. This doesn't matter in OpenOffice Calc and Gnumeric, which appear to operate on a "do what I mean" philosophy. In Excel 2003, you need to select the cell then hit F2 (forces it to decompile the formula from xlwt-generated bytecode to text) followed by `Enter` (makes it compile the text into bytecode that it's happy with). Working on this is very low on my list of priorities.